# Hierarchical Clustering: Extract observations from large heatmap

Tags: scikit-learn, hierarchical-clustering

I'm currently trying to visualize a large data set as heat map. That in itself works smoothly but I struggle with gaining insights from interestingly looking clusters.

Specifically, I have two questions that are very related:

First, I find clusters of interesting features and am looking for a systematic way to extract the a flat clustering at a specific level (but the [fcluster](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.fcluster.html#scipy.cluster.hierarchy.fcluster) function seems to do something different and [cut_tree](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.cluster.hierarchy.cut_tree.html) doesn't work with those trees). I would like to have a slice of the hierarchical clustering at a specified depth of the dendrogram. This is probably encoded in the linkage matrix `Z` but I struggle to understand how exactly I can extract that information from `Z`.

Second, with the complicated heatmap pictured below, the row names on the right are gene names for every 100th data point (gene). I would now like to have a look at which genes are in some of the little clusters, for instance the little black square for feature `MF: LIHC` that is marked.
[image: heatmap with interesting features]
I know the IDs of the genes that are labelled on the right, so I would want to know something like:

*Which genes are in the same cluster as CAPN7 at level 5?*

Thank you for your help!

Roman

Comment: What do the columns of the heatmap represent and what do the colours represent?

Comment: The columns are different data types for various different cancers. The color represents a value of feature importance from an algorithm and the rows represent ~15.000 genes.
Therefore, to interpret this heatmap, I have to get to the interesting clusters and compute representatives/prototypes or do pathway enrichment analyses or something like that.